# How to (correctly) install and import pymavlink using PIP

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I'm using OS X Yosemite and trying to setup pymavlink using pip and python 2.7.  Typed `sudo pip install pymavlink` and it installs beautifully.  Tried to import it with

```
from pymavlink import mavlinkv10 as mavlink
```

and the interpreter throws this error:

> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymavlink/mavlinkv10.py", line 10, in 
>   from ...generator.mavcrc import x25crc
>   ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package

I think I understand the error and can manually "fix" it by changing the package's implicit import "...generator" to explicit "pymavlink.generator".  My question is, what is the correct way to install and import this package using pip. I can't be the first person to have this issue :)

Comment: Someone reported it here, but it was closed without comment (hate when maintainers do that!): https://github.com/mavlink/mavlink/issues/150

Comment: Hey, thanks for chiming in. Not sure why they closed that issue since some of the documentation for setting up a mavlink environment seems deprecated. I raised the issue on gitter and one of the maintainers said that the above issue usually has to do with your PYTHONPATH not being set properly or, possibly, trying to load the module straight from the source (assuming he meant loading the module without first running mavgenerate). Welcome comments on how to make the PIP install of mavlink go smoothly.

Comment: I got the same error from a fresh pip install, so I'm not sure what that means.  The relative imports that mavlink does isn't a good idea in general, hopefully they'll just fix that.  What's the mavlink gitter url?

Comment: Sure, here are some of the relevant gitter chats:


https://gitter.im/mavlink/qgroundcontrol

https://gitter.im/diydrones/ardupilot

https://gitter.im/diydrones/dronekit-python

https://gitter.im/tridge/MAVProxy

Comment: Others having the same issue:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mavlink/FDLGJQNymFI

Answer (score 4):

*Doesn't look like anyone is chiming in on this one with a textbook answer, so I'll go ahead and post how I cobbled together a bush-league python mavlink installation on a Raspberry Pi and, hopefully, someone will post a legit solution in the future for how to correctly do it with PIP.  Welcome any comments/fixes!*

install pymavlink by typing "sudo pip install pymavlink".  This will install the pymavlink module (and the mavlinkv10.py file you'll have to modify) to following directory on your pi "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymavlink/"

import the pymavlink module with the following line at the beginning of your python code "from pymavlink import mavlinkv10 as mavlink"

When running the pymavlink example code from the pymavlink repository, the interpreter will first throw the following error:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymavlink/mavlinkv10.py"
in from ...generator.mavcrc import x25crc 
ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package
```

It looks like mavlinkv10.py is trying to do a relative import from 3 parent directories "up" (I think?).  Since the "generator" directory is actually a child directory under where mavlinkv10.py resides, I changed the following in mavlinkv10.py:

```
changed this:  from ...generator.mavcrc import x25crc
to this:       from generator.mavcrc import x25crc
```

Next, the interpreter will throw the following error when you run python mavlink code that tries to create (encode) a new mavlink message:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymavlink/mavlinkv10.py", line 1053, in pack
return MAVLink_message.pack(self, mav, 137, struct.pack('<QI', self.time_unix_usec, self.time_boot_ms))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymavlink/mavlinkv10.py", line 110, in pack
crc.accumulate(chr(crc_extra))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist packages/pymavlink/generator/mavcrc.py", line 18, in accumulate
tmp = b ^ (accum & 0xff)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'str' and 'int'
```

It appears the mavlinkv10 is failing on the extra crc calculation in the pack() function.  You can "fix" this error by turning off the extra crc stuff in mavlinkv10's pack() function.  Comment out these 2 lines in mavlinkv10.py:

```
#if True: # using CRC extra
#    crc.accumulate(chr(crc_extra))
```

Last thing.  You'll also need to also disable the crc2 calculation in the decode() function in mavlinkv10.py.  Comment out these lines in mavlinkv10.py:

```
#if True: # using CRC extra 
#    crc2.accumulate(chr(crc_extra))
#if crc != crc2.crc:
#    raise MAVError('invalid MAVLink CRC in msgID
```

At this point, you should be able to run pymavlink exemplar code, although I'm unclear how disabling the "extra CRC" calculation will impact mavlink reliability (probably not positively).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using

```
from pymavlink import mavlinkv10 as mavlink
```

try

```
from pymavlink.dialects.v10 import common as mavlink
```

replacing `common` with whatever dialect you may want (see the XML files in https://github.com/mavlink/mavlink/tree/master/message_definitions/v1.0 for all of the options)